# Send a text message directly via an IBAction (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

How do I send a text message (using `MFMessageComposeViewController`) directly via an IBAction? Like, when the button is pressed, a text message is sent with a preset number, and no keyboard shows up or anything. Just an alert saying "SMS was sent successfully," for example.

All the coding is done, except for this "direct sending-function".

Comment: Where do you want this message send to? To which object?

Comment: To multiple NSStrings :)

Comment: Do you mean SMS? Consider MFMessageComposeViewController.

Comment: Oh, sorry! Yes, that's right :)

Comment: Would you mind to correct the question so it reflects what you want to ask?

Comment: did u find any solution about ur question????
i need same solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you can't technically "auto-send" the message, because it will require user confirmation to go through.

You can, however, set up the message's contents and recipient(s) using [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html) (quite a mouthful) and display a dialog that will require one extra tap to send.

To have access to that dialog, you'll have to `#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>` and add `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` to your view controller declaration in your header file.

Then, you can write the `IBAction`. First, you want to check that the device can actually send messages with text content using [`canSendText`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MFMessageComposeViewController/canSendText). Then, you'll create the view controller, populate it with data, and present the dialog.

```
- (IBAction)sendMessage:(UIButton *)sender {
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
        MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init]; // Create message VC
        messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self; // Set delegate to current instance

        NSMutableArray *recipients = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // Create an array to hold the recipients
        [recipients addObject:@"555-555-5555"]; // Append example phone number to array
        messageController.recipients = recipients; // Set the recipients of the message to the created array

        messageController.body = @"Example message"; // Set initial text to example message

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // Present VC when possible
            [self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:NULL];
        });
    }
}
```

One last thing: you have to implement a delegate method to tell the message view controller to dismiss when the user presses "cancel" in the send dialog:

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Hmm, so there's no way of sending it directly without that extra tap? :/

Comment: @simonsayzhi Unfortunately, no. Otherwise, malicious apps could send spam messages to everyone in a user's address book in the background without the user's consent.